# How to show a blank line

Tags: support, markdown

I was wondering how to specify the spacing between "item2" and "postlist" to be the same as the spacing between "prelist" and "item1",  in the following example:

1. prelist:

   - item1.
   - item2

   postlist
2. prelist:

   - item1.
   - item2

   postlist

Comment: Surely someone will come up with a way that adds explicit line breaks. But please note that a plain web browser is not the only way the posts are used (think data dump, screen readers, mobile devices). And when rendering (or CSS) is tweaked in the future, specific hacks might result in bad rendering even for things that look fine today. I'd say: learn to live with the limitations of Markdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. prelist:

   - item1.
   - item2

   postlist
2. prelist:

   - item1.
   - item2

   postlist

---

```
1. prelist:

     - item1.
     - item2

    <br>
    postlist

1. prelist:

     - item1.
     - item2

    <br>
    postlist
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering: (1) if both Markdown  and HTML are both webpage languages, or if Markdown is a tool that convert text into HTML? (2)when they can be mixed together just like in your reply?

Comment: @Tim, they can be mixed together here, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user - but it depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Usually I do this with `&nbsp;` and two spaces (since two spaces create a line break).

1. prelist:

   - item1.
   - item2

   postlist
2. prelist:

   - item1.
   - item2

   postlist

Source:

```
1. prelist:
   - item1.
   - item2

   &nbsp;  
   postlist
2. prelist:
   - item1.
   - item2

   &nbsp;  
   postlist
```